# How to create class in salesforce using developer console

Tags: salesforce

I am getting Apex class does not exist error but i am not getting any option to create a class. Please see following screen shots.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you in a "non-Developer-Edition" Production org?

You must be in a Sandbox environment to create classes then deploy them to Production once tested.

If you logged from login.salesforce.com you're in a Prod instance, you must log from a different URL (test.salesforce.com) or from within the Prod org (Setup / Deploy / Sandboxes / then select the right org or create one).

Hope this make sense/help.